# xargs: running command once with all arguments

Tags: xargs

My aim is to get a list of files that have been modified in `git`, then run `rspec` command passing each file in as an argument.

Currently I have:

```
$ git status -s | awk '{if ($1 == "M") print $2}' | tr "\\n" "\\0" | \
    xargs -0 -I % rspec -f documentation %
```

This technically works, but it runs `rspec` for each modified file, I want it to run:

```
$ rspec path/to/file/1 path/to/file/2 ...
```

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: A shorter variant for the second command: `awk '/^ M / {print $2}'` (see [examples](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_3.html))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
... | xargs -0 rspec -f documentation
```

Note that this can call `rspec` multiple times if the command line would be too long. This isn't an issue with `rspec` since the reason to call it once is performance, but don't use it for something like `xargs -0 tar cf archive.tar` where any second, third, … run would create an archive overwriting the output of the previous runs.

Comment: Damn, knew I was doing something wrong.. Thanks

Comment: in your `tar` example you could use -x to force xargs to abort if the line is too long.